# Image Sequencer using CoreAnimation

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a list of images (say 180 images of sequence) to animate. If I use UIImageView with its default image sequence, I get memory issue.

I wanted to use CoreAnimation API, but really don't know how to do it?

What is the best way to do this.

Regards

iWasRobot :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very hard to google example on how to perform view transitions with Animation, here it is:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html 
Here you would need as little as 2 views. You would load images into the hidden view, then "transition" it in. Assuming your slideshow mode is long enough, you should have no issues with loading times.

Another thing that comes to mind is paging with UIScrollView. Here you would need as little as 3 views
http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/

I hope this helps!